# Create and List template in one Page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on a modal where there should be a table (display of selected data from another table) and textboxes at the same time. But I can't seem to find a way to combine a Create or Edit template with a List template in one page. Is there anyway I can do that?

Comment: Use a view model with properties for the new object and collection of objects, or use `@Html.Action()` in the view to call server methods that return partial views of your object and/or collection of objects.

Comment: @StephenMuecke So there isn't any way that I could combine a Create and List Template in one page or one modal Sir?

Comment: Yes of course. Read my previous comment.

Comment: @StephenMuecke right. Thank you for the response Sir.